# multicolumn css make the adjacent div in same height

Tags: html, css

Please refer the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkpqa/)

Here we have displayed the content as

box1

box2

box3

box4

box5

box6

using multi-column css we have changed the display as

box1        box4

box2        box5

box3        box6

The css we used is as follows:

```
      .columnsmulti {
            -moz-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-gap: 10px;
        -moz-column-rule: 0px double #666;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
        -webkit-column-rule: 0px double #666;
        column-count: 2;
        column-gap: 10px;
        column-rule: 0px double #666; width:400px;
    }  


    .blue_bx{ width:190px; background:#6BBEBD; background-repeat:repeat-y; float:left; font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;}

    .store_img img{ width:188px; height:75px; margin-top:1px; margin-left:1px; border:0px;}

    .store_name { float: left; width:150px; }

    .circle_ico{ float:right; padding-top:5px; padding-right:8px;}

    .store_name, .store_name a{ color:#FEFFD6;  font-family: 'impactregular'; font-size:20px; padding-left:5px; }

    .store_category, .store_category a{ width:170px; margin:0 auto; font-size:14px; color:#FDF279; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; display: block;  }
```

Now the desired output is: the adjacent div boxes should be in same height (if the box 1 content is more than box 4 then the box 1 and box 4 should be in box1's height). How to achieve this? Please help.

Comment: In css I don't know because it's static, but look this js library ["Equalize"](http://tsvensen.github.com/equalize.js/)

Comment: How about writing a JavaScript function that takes the heights of the two divs, compares them and resize them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the css property `min-height`

e.g: `min-height:85px;`

Find an appropriate min-height.
My guess would be like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bkpqa/1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/bkpqa/2/

If your loading dynamic content, than you need to adjust a `min-height` in javascript with the `.height()` getter.

Comment: If there are two lines in left box and one line in right box the both boxes should take left box's height. If I set min-height all the boxes take same height irrespective of the content in it.

Comment: That's why you have to class them two by two. Other than that you'll need javascript. Heres' an example: http://jsfiddle.net/bkpqa/2/